# Is it possible to add flags by default to Docker run

Tags: docker, sysctl

I'd like to know if it's possible to configure the docker engine to always add a custom flag (--sysctl) for all containers?

My problem is that I'am a rancher user, and rancher doesn't support the --sysctl flag. I'am looking for a workarround to this.

Thank you.

Comment: Try updating the `DOCKER_OPTS` line in `/etc/default/docker`, adding what you want. Restart docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

From [rancher-version - v1.2.0-pre4-rc4](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/4708)  sysctl option is supported.
Add appropriate option in launchconfig:

```
"launchConfig": {
"type": "launchConfig",
"sysctl": <options-here>
}
```

Comment: The launchConfig property is only accessible via the rancher API isn't it?